# Why does the roblox api keep 403'ing me?

Tags: javascript, roblox

Right now im using an x-csrf token, ctype password and cvalue (my actual username with cvalue and password), user id which is jsut some random letters, for captcha token i wrote in CAPTCHATOKENFROMFUNCAPTCHA, captcha provider as arkose labs and "captcha" as captchaid. Default stuff for headers, nothing roblox specific.
What else do i need? do i need to render an  actual captcha?
To bypass CORS im using roproxy.

ive trierd copying the cookies from the official roblox login page requests , and trying to get the authority to count as roblox.com. dosent seem to work.
Response is just 403 code 0